# Django Crispy forms with ModelForm, none type has no attribute fields, wrap_together

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Im new to crispy forms and am trying to add some layout to the forms, by putting them in three groups, then id like to put them in some panels (im using boostrap3)

this is my forms.py

```
class EditSiteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteData
        fields = ['location', 'site_type', 'bgp_as', 'opening_date','last_hw_refresh_date','is_live',
                    'tel','address','town','postcode',
                    'regional_manager','regional_manager_tel','assistant_manager','assistant_manager_tel' ,'duty_manager','duty_manager_tel']

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.add_input(Submit('Save', 'Save', css_class='btn-primary'))
    helper[0:5].wrap_together(Field, 'Details')
    helper[6:9].wrap_together(Field, 'Address')
    helper[10:15].wrap_together(Field, 'Showroom Contacts')
```

when I load the page I get
    Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py" in edit_site
  829.     from sites.forms import EditSiteForm

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/forms.py" in <module>
  35. class EditSiteForm(forms.ModelForm):

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/forms.py" in EditSiteForm
  46.     helper[0:5].wrap_together(Field, 'Details')

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crispy_forms/layout_slice.py" in wrap_together
  107.                 LayoutClass, self.layout.fields[self.slice], *args, **kwargs

Exception Type: AttributeError at /sites/edit/7
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

is modelform not support in crispy? do I need to issue each field manually first?

Thanks

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Traceback added

Comment: Where did you see examples of using FormHelper at class level? The docs only show it defined as an instance attribute, and you need to pass `self` to it.

Comment: this article https://godjango.com/29-crispy-forms/